# How to call C# methode from third party dll in Java?

Tags: java, c#, dll

I have a [third party dll](https://taskscheduler.codeplex.com/) file written with C#. It has some objects named TaskService, TaskDefinition, TaskScheduler. These classes also have some methods and member variables which i want to call from java.  How can i do that ?

Let's say i have the following C# code. Then how can i convert that code in Java ?

```
TaskService taskService = new TaskService();
TaskDefinition taskDefinition = taskService.NewTask();
taskDefinition.RegistrationInfo.Description = "MyAPP Skip UAC";
taskDefinition.Triggers.Add(new Microsoft.Win32.TaskScheduler.LogonTrigger() { UserId = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name });
taskDefinition.Actions.Add(new Microsoft.Win32.TaskScheduler.ExecAction() {     Path = Application.ExecutablePath.ToString().ToLower() });
taskDefinition.Principal.RunLevel = TaskRunLevel.Highest;
taskService.RootFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition("MyAppSkipUAC",taskDefinition);
```

I have googled a lot but didn't find a proper way to achieve it or any code snippets. All i got was calling C/C++ dlls from Java and calling c# method.  I am open to any types os solution. Any third party library or JNA/JNI approach would be ok.

Comment: You will have to define an API between the functions exposed within your dll and Java. The technology to implement the API would be indeed JNI. It may be, that you could achieve similar calls using windows scripting host scripts, but I'm not that deep in the topic.

Comment: Ditch Java and replace it with C# altogether.

Answer (score 0):

**JNIforNET**

I would use  jni4net library:
https://github.com/jni4net

I never used it but from the wiki looks like it creates automatically proxies to/from java to/from C# that allows you to call dll from java. It is built on top of JNI and basically writes the C/C++ for you.

Hope this helps.